# What is Distributed Lock Server

Tags: service, distributed, locking

What is Distributed Lock Service (or Server)? When it needs to be used?

Comment: You don't even necessarily need a special-purpose distribute lock server; in many cases a relational database can provide this functionality. For example, [This post](http://www.codeducky.org/distributed-locking-with-net-and-sqlserver/) describes how to use SQLServer for distributed locking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often called a Distributed Lock Manager, it's a way for distributed applications to control access to shared resources. A typical example would be a cluster of computers that present what seems to be a single unified file system, even though behind the scenes they are sharing a collection of file systems. Machines in the cluster would need a (distributed) lock in order to make changes to a file, to prevent race conditions.

Comment: Are any significant open source distributed lock manager that worth looking?